# Convertir query en Lista python

Tags: python, django

Quiero convertir este query `Clientes.objects.values()` en una lista para posteriormente usar las gráficas Chartkick pero con los valores que me regresa.

El modelo `Clientes` es:

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False)
    medio = models.ForeignKey(Medio,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Nombre
```

Y lo que quiero es que usando Chartkick me mande el número de personas dependiendo del campo `medio`, cabe mencionar que los medios son dinámicos al igual que el número de personas.

Comment: Amigo, no entiendo que quieres decir con que los medios son dinámicos al igual que el número de personas. Ya has intentando alguna query?

Comment: Si para traer todo lo de Clientes en este caso hago Clientes.objects.values() y obtengo su nombre y su medio , lo que quiero realizar es que dependiendo el medio me cuente las personas y me genere la gráfica con chartkick

Comment: Angel, ¿el modelo `Persona` se llama.... `Clientes`? Por favor, revisa tu pregunta para que quede todo claro

Comment: Si perdón es Clientes

Comment: Estoy resivando la documentación de `chartkick`, sería muy útil si nos dijeras que entradas recibe `chartkick` para hacer las gráficas, nuevamente, revisa mi respuesta para ver si te ayuda en algo.

Comment: Amigo @César, tu eres el maestro, deja unas respuestas para los novatos :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, para empezar puedes usar una búsqueda simple con django en tu modelo clientes:

```
Clientes.objects.filter(medio='whatever').count()
```

La función `filter`filtra todos los objetos del modelo según la búqueda que necesites, la función `count` cuenta todos los objetos hallados en dicha búsqueda.

Para mas información puedes usar la documentación: [Filtrar en Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Ahora bien, necesitas usar `chartkick` lo que quieres es crear un diccionario con los nombres de cada medio y un el número de clientes de cada medio, para ello puedes hacer una lista o un arreglo con todos los nombres de los medios, o en su defecto, hacer una búsqueda para encontrar los medios existentes en cliente, y luego hacer una iteración que te cree un arreglo con el nombre de dicho medio y como valor la búsqueda que te puse anteriormente, puede ser de la siquiente manera:

```
var data = []
for medio in medios:
    data.append(medio, Clientes.objects.filter(medio=medio).count()))
```

Suponiendo que `data` será la lista de datos que utilizará la librería, tal como dice en su documentación: [[['Chrome', 52.9], ['Firefox', 27.7], ['Opera', 1.6]]](https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py#data)

Creamos una lista medios que tendrá como objetos el nombre del medio, y en una iteración vamos a agregar a la lista data el valor medio obtenido en medios y el número de objetos que tiene la lista medios.

A grandes rasgos debe ser una solición de ese estilo. El último paso sería llamas la lista generada desde Django, pero para ello puedes usar esta lista en la una vista basada en clases como contexto adicional.

Para ello podemos ver el [Ejemplo de Vista de Lista](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) en la documentación:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

En esta función podemos añadir el contenido adicional que queremos que la plantilla muestre en pantalla:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        var data = []
        for medio in medios:
            data.append(medio, Clientes.objects.filter(medio=medio).count()))
        context['data'] = data
        return context
```

Con esto pasaremos la variable data como el contexto data en la vista de lista, o si quieres, en una vista detallada, y eso sería suficiente.

Comment: Si eso me queda claro ya tengo los de cada uno

medio1=Clientes.objects.filter(medio='1').count()
medio2=Clientes.objects.filter(medio='2').count()
medio3=Clientes.objects.filter(medio='3').count()

por ejemplo el punto es como integrarlo a chartkick

Comment: Ah amigo, perfecto, voy a ponerte acá un ejemplo simple, por que no tengo a mano django, pero seguro puede ser muy útil.
Una pregunta más, los medios tienen nombres o son sólo números?

Comment: Medios es un modelo diferente y solo tienen nombre

Comment: Ahí si es mas complicado, voy a ponerte un ejemplo de como debería ser, y en la noche te ayudo más detalladamente.

Comment: +1 es una posible solución, habría que saber si relamente está usando Vistas Basadas en Clase (VBC) o en funciones (VBF)

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es algún tipo de gráfico en el que tengas la cantidad de clientes por medio. Si ese es el caso entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es agruparlos.

Para agruparlos, creo que en este caso lo más sencillo sería empezar desde la inversa, es decir, desde el modelo `Medio`. Haciendo uso del método [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) y [`Count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count) podemos contar la cantidad de clientes que tiene cada medio:

```
>>> data = Medio.objects.annotate(total=Count('clientes')).values_list('nombre', 'total')
[('MEDIO1', 10), ('MEDIO2', 20), ('MEDIO3', 30)]
```

Ten en cuenta que estoy usando `values_list` en vez de `values` para representar los resultados a través de tuplas. Estoy asumiendo también que tu modelo `Medio` tiene un campo `nombre`.

De acuerdo al a documentación que veo en el repositorio de [Chartkick](https://github.com/mher/chartkick.py), la `data` puede ser un diccionario o una lista:

```
{'Chrome': 52.9, 'Opera': 1.6, 'Firefox': 27.7}

[['Chrome', 52.9], ['Firefox', 27.7], ['Opera', 1.6]]
```

No se si Chartkick acepte una lista de tuplas pero mejor nos aseguramos y la convertimos a una lista de listas:

```
>>> data = Medio.objects.annotate(total=Count('clientes')).values_list('nombre', 'total')
[('MEDIO1', 10), ('MEDIO2', 20), ('MEDIO3', 30)]
>>> data = [list(elem) for elem in data]
[['MEDIO1', 10], ['MEDIO2', 20], ['MEDIO3', 30]]
```

Creo que con esto ya tienes lista la `data` para pasarla a Chartkick.

Comment: No conocía esa función `annotate`, gracias, como siempre. Mejor respuesta que la mía :'(, este me da una idea :D

Comment: @SalahAdDin no se si mejor, pero si diferente. Todos los días aprendemos algo nuevo ;-)

Comment: Bueno, un punto para mi respuesta, por lo menos está completamente redactada :'(

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo se me hizo mucho mas fácil así aun así gracias a los 2 @SalahAdDin,

Answer (score -1):

Disculpen ahora me están pidiendo filtro por fechas, Requiero Dia, MEs , 3 Meses anteriores etc , Checando la documentación de Chartkick veo que funcionaria un range pero como lo puedo incluir a lo que ya tengo

```
def charts(request):
data = Clasificacion.objects.annotate(total=Count('carros')).values_list('nombre','total',).order_by('-total')
data = [list(elem) for elem in data]
library = {
        "backgroundColor": "#FFF",
        "colors": ['#21333a','#76b5cd','#436775','#548192','#659bb0']
        }
template = 'templates/Usuarios/Reporte_Cliente.html'
return render(request, template, locals())
```

y en mi modelo clientes añadi el campo correspondiente

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
```

Comment: Debes realizar otra pregunta aparte para esta solicitud nueva